# I'm trying to make a calculator but it doesn't work

Tags: python, calculator

I'm new to python and trying to make a calculator. The actual calculator part works but I can't figure out how to make it so that when the user puts in something that is not "+, -, *, or /" it prints a sentence then closes.

This is my code and the output

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYzxg.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

```
if choice in ["+", "/", "*", "-"]:
  [do stuff]
if choice not in ["+", "/", "*", "-"]:
  [do stuff]
```

Though this is not the best way to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

The code you are trying to achieve:

```py
choice = input("Enter '+' for addition, LA for subtraction, * for multiplication, and '/' for division: ")
if (choice == "+" or choice == "-" or choice == "*" or choice == "/"):
    num1 = float(input("Enter the first number:"))
    num2 = float(input("Enter the second number:"))
    if choice == "+":
        print(num1, "+", num2, "=", (num1 + num2))
        exit()
    if choice == "-":
        print(num1, "-", num2, "=", (num1 - num2))
        exit()
    if choice == "*":
        print(num1, "*", num2, "=", (num1 * num2))
        exit()
    if choice == "/":
        print(num1, "/", num2, "=", (num1 / num2))
        exit()
if (choice != "+" or choice != "-" or choice !="*" or choice !="/"):
    print("That's not an option.....")
    exit()
```

You cannot directly compare the values like a = b c d rather we should mention compare for each value like
a == b or a == c or a == d, where 'or' is an operator
for logical conditions.

'else' can also be used instead of second condition here for better code optimization.